# git pull/clone private repo using bash script only

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I am new to github and bash scripting, so help will be appreciated.

I want to run a script that will clone a private github repo into my instance. Since the repo is private, I understand that I need to do this through ssh. So my script starts like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
#HOW DO I ADD THE SSH TO GITHUB FROM THIS SCRIPT
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

However the next step is that I need to manually go into github in order to add the SSH key into my settings. Is there anyway I can do all of this through the script itself?

Thanks

Comment: You need to run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` only once and update your public key in github.

Comment: @alnet but I still have to go into github manually...

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so you would need to authorize your script to use [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and add your newly generated public key via [corresponding method](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/) with `curl` or something of a sort.